# javascript - add object at the beginning on each map iteration

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, object, addition

So, let's suppose I have this:

```
var officers = [
  { id: 20, name: 'Captain', lastName: 'Piett' },
  { id: 24, name: 'General', lastName: 'Veers'  },
  { id: 56, name: 'Admiral', lastName: 'Ozzel'  },
  { id: 88, name: 'Commander', lastName: 'Jerjerrod'  }
];
```

If I do this: 
`var officersIds = officers.map(x => [x.name, x.lastName]);`
the result of `officersIds` is gonna be this:

```
[ "Captain", "Piett" ], [ "General", "Veers" ], [ "Admiral", "Ozzel" ], [ "Commander", "Jerjerrod" ]
```

right?

So, what I need to do is to put an object on each map iteration so the output is now this, for example:

```
[["x", "y"], [ "Captain", "Piett" ]], 
[["x", "y"], [ "General", "Veers" ]],  
[["x", "y"], [ "Admiral", "Ozzel" ]], 
[["x", "y"], [ "Commander", "Jerjerrod" ]]
```

Why do I need this? Better don't ask ;) But it's a complex problem and if you help me solve this simple one I could transfer your solution to my complex problem.

**IMPORTANT: Is there a way to do this in one line?**

Comment: You mean you need to put one new element, `["x", "y"]`, at the start of `officersIds`?

Comment: Your example looks almost identical to what you already do. You mention objects but I see none? What exactly is the desired output?

Comment: `officers.map(x => [["x", "y"], [x.name, x.lastName]])`. Just return a 2D array from map callback.

Comment: I'm sorry , I corrected the output

Comment: well, this does the trick, were can I find the answer to mark it solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply want to add `['x', 'y']` to the start of the array, you can use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to make it a one-liner:

```
var officersIds = [['x', 'y'], ...officers.map(x => [x.name, x.lastName])];
```

See proof-of-concept below:

```js
var officers = [
  { id: 20, name: 'Captain', lastName: 'Piett' },
  { id: 24, name: 'General', lastName: 'Veers'  },
  { id: 56, name: 'Admiral', lastName: 'Ozzel'  },
  { id: 88, name: 'Commander', lastName: 'Jerjerrod'  }
];

var officersIds = [['x', 'y'], ...officers.map(x => [x.name, x.lastName])];

console.log(officersIds);
```

---

However, if you want to add `['x', 'y']` to each item in the array, then you should do this instead:

```
var officersIds = officers.map(x => [['x', 'y'], [x.name, x.lastName]]);
```

```js
var officers = [
  { id: 20, name: 'Captain', lastName: 'Piett' },
  { id: 24, name: 'General', lastName: 'Veers'  },
  { id: 56, name: 'Admiral', lastName: 'Ozzel'  },
  { id: 88, name: 'Commander', lastName: 'Jerjerrod'  }
];

var officersIds = officers.map(x => [['x', 'y'], [x.name, x.lastName]]);

console.log(officersIds);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var officers = [
  { id: 20, name: 'Captain', lastName: 'Piett' },
  { id: 24, name: 'General', lastName: 'Veers'  },
  { id: 56, name: 'Admiral', lastName: 'Ozzel'  },
  { id: 88, name: 'Commander', lastName: 'Jerjerrod' },
];

officers.unshift({ name: x, lastName: y });

var officersIds = officers.map(x => [x.name, x.lastName]);
```

Or

```
var officers = [
      { id: 20, name: 'Captain', lastName: 'Piett' },
      { id: 24, name: 'General', lastName: 'Veers'  },
      { id: 56, name: 'Admiral', lastName: 'Ozzel'  },
      { id: 88, name: 'Commander', lastName: 'Jerjerrod' },
    ];


    var officersIds = officers.map(x => [x.name, x.lastName]);

    officersIds.unshift(["x", "y" ]);
```

Comment: probably missing some quotes

Answer (score 0):

Use Map over `officers`.

```js
var officers = [
  { id: 20, name: 'Captain', lastName: 'Piett' },
  { id: 24, name: 'General', lastName: 'Veers'  },
  { id: 56, name: 'Admiral', lastName: 'Ozzel'  },
  { id: 88, name: 'Commander', lastName: 'Jerjerrod'  }
];

var officersIds = officers.map(x => [["x", "y"], [x.name, x.lastName]]);
   
console.log(officersIds);
```

Comment: `.splice(0, 0, x)` can be written `.unshift(x)`.

Answer (score 0):

You could just add the wanted parts to the mapping function.

```js
var officers = [{ id: 20, name: 'Captain', lastName: 'Piett' }, { id: 24, name: 'General', lastName: 'Veers'  }, { id: 56, name: 'Admiral', lastName: 'Ozzel'  }, { id: 88, name: 'Commander', lastName: 'Jerjerrod'  }],
    officersIds = officers.map(x => [["x", "y"], [x.name, x.lastName]]);

console.log(officersIds);
```